# Why can I not assign dataSource directly?

Tags: swift, uitableview, datasource

I would like to understand why to following Swift code does not work, but using the commented version does. I'm not sure if dataSources are typically wrapped into a separate class, but I don't think that should matter. I'm using Xcode 6.3.2, all up to date.

```
// MainViewController.swift
import UIKit
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataSource:UITableViewDataSource?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // dataSource = MainTableViewDataSource()
        // tableView.dataSource = dataSource

        tableView.dataSource = MainTableViewDataSource()
    }
}
```

The MainTableViewDataSource is just a class which implements the UITableViewDataSource protocol and uses some dummy data.

```
// MainTableViewDataSource.swift
import UIKit

class MainTableViewDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1000
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return String(section + 1)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Joejoe"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" in what sense? Compiler error, runtime error, wrong results, ... ?

Comment: Sorry, it throws a runtime error. Don't get a lot of info in the console though: '(lldb)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource

**dataSource** property of UITableView is **unowned** in Swift which is **(assign)** for Objective-C meaning that this property does not increase the reference count. So right after **viewDidLoad** function, when reference count of your **MainTableViewDataSource** becomes zero, it gets deallocated.

I recommend reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

You'll run into strange outcomes--sometimes even inconsistent--if you don't do the memory management right.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was unfamiliar with the unowned concept. It actually makes perfect sense now, thank you!